# Different order of paths in sys.path between the linked python binary and the original one

Tags: python-2.7, centos, virtualenv

There is a python project which is deployed by using virtualenv. Simplified version of the build script is next:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages runtime
source ./runtime/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt --index-url=...
deactivate
```

After build we'll end with some python binaries in `runtime/bin/`:

```
[....@... project1]$ ll runtime/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 лис 15 13:26 runtime/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 лис 15 13:26 runtime/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4864 лис 15 13:26 runtime/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2350 лис 15 13:26 runtime/bin/python-config
```

For convenience there is a symlink to `runtime/bin/python2.7` in the other directory: `bin`; the `bin` directory located on the same level as `runtime`:

```
[...@... project1]$ ll
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  4096 лис 15 19:27 bin
....
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  4096 лис 15 13:26 runtime
...

[...@... project1]$ ll bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 лис 15 19:27 bin/python -> ../runtime/bin/python2.7
```

And here are the strange things I can see in `sys.path` from linked and original binaries:

```
[...@... project1]$ bin/python -c "import sys, pprint;pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
['',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_config',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1.api.activities',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_comments',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_oauthorizer',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_social',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_bulk',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_core',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_tags',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_messages',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_sync',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_contacts',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_search',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_deals',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_wufoo',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_mailchimp',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_insights',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_marketing',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/amqp-1.4.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrasite-2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.14-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-0.7.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum34-1.0.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1-0.1.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/media/ephemeral0/nimble/runtime/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']


[...@... project1]$ runtime/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pprint;pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
['',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_config',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1.api.activities',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_comments',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_oauthorizer',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_social',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_bulk',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_core',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_tags',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_messages',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_sync',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_contacts',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_search',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_deals',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_wufoo',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_mailchimp',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_insights',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/src/project1_marketing',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/amqp-1.4.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Pillow-2.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrasite-2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyOpenSSL-0.14-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-0.7.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum34-1.0.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyasn1-0.1.7-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi-0.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

... order of the paths is different! For example: position of the `'/media/ephemeral0/project1/runtime/lib/python2.7/site-packages',`.
How is it possible? There are no `.pth` files in the `bin` (symlink's location) directory and I can not understand who is culprit.